# Convert underscores to hyphens in angular variable

Tags: css, angularjs

I have data icons whose classes are formatted by vehicle type and then sub-type, like so:

```
.di-icon-type-car-full-size-car
.di-icon-type-car-mid-size-car
.di-icon-type-van-large-van
.di-icon-type-van-minivan
```

In my view I am trying to dynamically set the class based on the current vehicle's information:

```
span(ng-class="'di-icon-type-' + vehicle.type + '-' + vehicle.sub_type")
```

The problem is, my `vehicle.sub_type` variable is formatted with underscores, not dashes. So the class appears as `di-icon-type-car-full_size_car` instead of `di-icon-type-car-full-size-car`, for example. Is there a way I can convert all underscores in my `vehicle.sub_type` variable to hyphens before using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to move a string concatenation and dash normalization into a function in a controller like this:

```
$scope.getIconClass = function(vehicle) {
  var className = 'di-icon-type-' + vehicle.type + '-' + vehicle.sub_type;
  return className.replace(/_/g, '-');
};
```

Then use it like this in the template:

```
<span ng-class="getIconClass(vehicle)"></span>
```

Alternatively, you could write a custom filter to do the job:

```
.filter('kebabcase', function() {
  return function (value) {
    return value && value.replace(/_/g, '-');
  };
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
<span ng-class="'di-icon-type-' + vehicle.type + '-' + vehicle.sub_type | kebabcase"></span>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/dRj6Sf3NeUq8IxnBshyE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
span(ng-class="'di-icon-type-' + vehicle.type.replace(/_/g, "-") + '-' + vehicle.sub_type")
```

should work for you

Comment: This only replaces the first underscore

Comment: My bad! It's been amended to replace all underscores :)

Comment: Give the latest edit one last shot. Didn't check the answer properly when I had posted it, sorry about that.